# ImageView frame with autolayout

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard

I'm using autolayout with imageview, but when image is resized frame is still big and my constraints  are to image frame not bounds. Here is picture: http://i57.tinypic.com/a3p852.png Constraint value is 3px, but distance is much bigger. Is there way to force image frame to be exactly as bounds? I know that I can do this in code, but I'm looking for the way in storyboard.

EDIT:
ImageView is in Aspect Fit mode, here are constrains of imageview: http://i60.tinypic.com/fxv236.png

Comment: What is the content mode? Scale to fill? scale to fit?

Comment: You need to tell us what constraints you have on your image view.